# Problems with an animation and hover on a button

Tags: html, css

So I have created a button that has an animation - when the page runs it pops up after 3-4 seconds and when the user hovers it has to become wider. The problem is when I hover it the pop-up animation starts again and runs every time I hover. In the CSS file it starts at header .down_text .button-play which is about 140 line.

```css
   


header {
 background: url('../img/2.jpg') no-repeat center center;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
}

header .sticky {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 999;
}

header .sticky:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: #000;
 height: 90px;
 opacity: 0.8;
}

header .sticky .logo {
 float: left;
}

header .sticky .logo i {
 font-size: 50px;
 margin-top: 19px;
 color: white;
 animation-name: logo;
 animation-duration: 2s;
 transition-property: transform;
 transition-duration: 1s;
}

.logo i:hover {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


header .sticky .main-nav {
 float: right;
 margin-top: 32px;
}

header .sticky .main-nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

header .sticky .main-nav a {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #FFF;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 transition: 0.5s; 
}

header .sticky .main-nav ul li a:hover {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

header .up_text {
 position: absolute;
 top: 80px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 color: #FFF;
}

header .down_text {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 80px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 color: #FFF;
}

header .up_text h1 {
 font-size: 80px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: 'Acme', sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ACAD9E;
 animation: heading;
 animation-duration: 5s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes heading {
 0% {opacity: 0}
 100% {opacity: 1}
}

header .down_text .button-play {
 position: relative;
 width: 270px;
 height: 56px;
 background: #ffa84c; /* Old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffa84c 0%, #ff7b0d 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#ffa84c 0%, #ff7b0d 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffa84c 0%, #ff7b0d 100%);  
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffa84c', endColorstr='#ff7b0d',GradientType=0 );
 font-family: 'Acme', sans-serif;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 25px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 border: none;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 font-weight: bolder;
 animation: popUp normal forwards ease-in-out;
 animation-duration: 5s;
}

header .down_text .button-play:hover {
 background: #e67700;
 animation: splash 1s normal forwards ease-in-out;
 animation-duration: 0.5s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes popUp {
 0% {opacity: 0}
 100% {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes splash {
 0% {width: 270px; opacity: 1}
 100% {width: 300px; opacity: 1}
}

/*@keyframes play {
 0% {bottom: 0;}
 50% {bottom: 10px;}
 100% {bottom: 0px;}
}*/


header .down_text p {
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 font-size: 35px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 font-weight: bolder;
 animation: heading;
 animation-delay: 1s;
 animation-duration: 5s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 opacity: 0;
}















/*MEDIA QUERIES ---------------------------------*/

/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {

}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {

}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
 <title>Fortnite</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/reset.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

 <!-- jQuery & Ajax --> 

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


 

<header>
   <div class="sticky">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div class="logo">
        <a href="#">
         <i class="fab fa-foursquare"></i>
        </a>
       </div>
       <div class="main-nav collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul>
         <li>
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a href="gameplay.html">Gameplay</a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a href="players.html">players</a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a href="battle-pass.html">battle pass</a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a href="skins.html">skins</a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a href="about.html">about</a>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="up_text">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
       <h1>FORTNITE</h1>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="down_text">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
      <a href="#"><button type="button" class="button-play">START PLAYING!</button></a>
       <p>WELCOME TO THE BEST BATTLE ROYAL GAME EVER MADE!</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>


 






 <!-- The jQuery CDN goes before the JS -->
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <!-- AJAX -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you cannot solve it by using pure CSS.

So I declared a new class `pop-up` with the animation and add it the button:

```
header .pop-up {
  animation: popUp normal forwards ease-in-out;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}
```

Than with jQuery the class will be remove on `mouseover`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button-play").mouseover(function() {
    if ($(".button-play").hasClass("pop-up")) {
      $(this).removeClass("pop-up");
    } else {
      // do something
    }
  });
});
```

[See the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/gq2cwzjf/20/)